# CDI @Produces Javadoc requirement explanation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, javabeans, producer-consumer

I'm wondering about this requirement described in the **@Produces** [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Produces.html):

> *If a producer method sometimes returns a null value, or if a producer*
>   *field sometimes contains a null value when accessed, then the producer*
>   *method or field must have scope @Dependent.*

What is the relation between the scope and the produced value?

Comment: Not exactly sure how the quoted Javadoc relates to your question, but maybe these links can help: [scopes](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#scopes), [scopes and contexts](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#contexts), [dependent pseudo-scope](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#dependent_context), and [producer methods](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#producer_method).

Answer (score 0):

The scope annotation on a producer method notionally describes the thing being produced.  This sentence is saying that it is only when `@Dependent` annotates your producer method that its return values may be `null`.  The `null` object, when produced by a producer method or producer field, in other words, may only ever be a member of the `@Dependent` scope.

Answer (score 0):

Every bean in CDI has a scope attached to it. The scope determines the context it lives in which in turn controls the lifecycle its beans. Even if you don't explicitly state a scope, there is always one; `@Dependent` is assumed if no other scope was specified.

Now, a bean can be a class, producer method or producer field (actually there are synthetic ones too few more other things can be considered beans but let's leave that aside for now). Therefore even producers need to define a scope of the bean they produce.

Here is some code:

```
@Produces
@Dependent //annotatation is not needed, it would be assumed automatically
public String produceDependentBean() {
  if (isTodayMonday()) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return "foo";
  }
}

// this one is going to throw an exception once used, you cannot return null and have other then dependent scope
@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
public String produceIllegalStuff() {
  return null;
}
```

The part of specification you quoted just says that in case a producer method returns `null` in some cases, then it *has to be `@Dependent`*. It is noteworthy that returning `null` from producers is a rather rare use case but the spec needed to be clear nonetheless.